# Problem making live app with react native and nodejs

Tags: node.js, react-native

i'm really confused if is it possible to make a live quizz app with multiplayer mode using react native or not ? if so please give me the approach you would take (I'm good at react native and nodejs)

Comment: Look into socket.io for the node.js backend to support a live multiplayer type feature. Anything is possible :)

Comment: Thank you bro :D